# error when get list from one to many relationship , Unknown column '***' in field list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

i create a simple Hibernate project with intellj , CRUD classes and relative Entities but when i try to retrieve items from a departments this error code comes out

here involved classes

DepartmentsEntity.java

```
package database_table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

 /**
  * Created by Michele on 14/07/2017.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments", schema = "warehouse")
public class DepartmentsEntity {
private String name;
private int id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departments",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch = 
FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ItemsEntity> items;

public List<ItemsEntity> getItems() {
    return this.items;
}
public void setItems (List<ItemsEntity> items){
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    DepartmentsEntity that = (DepartmentsEntity) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return 
 false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String res = "///Departments///";
    res += "\nID:          "+this.getId();
    res += "\nname:        "+this.getName();
    return res;
    }
}
```

ItemsEntity.java

```
package database_table;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Michele on 14/07/2017.
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "items", schema = "warehouse")
public class ItemsEntity {
private String name;
private Integer price;
private Integer size;
private int id;
private String description;

@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "price")
public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "size")
public Integer getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(Integer size) {
    this.size = size;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name = "dep" , nullable = false)//nome colonna della table items nel database warehouse
private DepartmentsEntity departments;//nome oggetto nel mappedBy di DepartmentsEntity(l'entita di destinazione)
                                      //che contiene una List di Item
public DepartmentsEntity getDepartments(){return this.departments;}
public void setDepartments(DepartmentsEntity departments){this.departments = departments;}


@OneToMany (mappedBy = "items",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column (name = "id")
private List<MovementsEntity> movements;
/*public ArrayList<MovementsEntity> getMovements(){return this.movements;}
public void setMovements(ArrayList<MovementsEntity> movements){this.movements = movements;}*/


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    ItemsEntity that = (ItemsEntity) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
    if (price != null ? !price.equals(that.price) : that.price != null) return false;
    if (size != null ? !size.equals(that.size) : that.size != null) return false;
    if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (price != null ? price.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (size != null ? size.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + id;
    result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

public void replaceItem(ItemsEntity item){
    if(item.name!= "" || item.name!=null){
        this.setName(item.name);
    }
    if(item.price!=null){
        this.setPrice(item.price);
    }
    if(item.size!=null){
        this.setSize(item.size);
    }
    if(item.description!= "" || item.description!=null){
        this.setDescription(item.description);
    }
    if(item.departments.getName()!= "" || item.departments!=null){
        this.setDepartments(item.departments);
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String res = "///Item///";
    res += "\nID:          "+this.getId();
    res += "\nname:        "+this.getName();
    res += "\nprice:       "+this.getDescription();
    res += "\nstored size: "+this.getSize();
    res += "\ndepartment:  "+this.getDepartments().getName();
    return res;
}
}
```

DepartmentsCRUD.java

```
package service;

import database_table.DepartmentsEntity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michele on 14/07/2017.
 */
public class DepartmentsCRUD {

protected EntityManager em;

public DepartmentsCRUD (EntityManager em){
    this.em = em;
}

public List<DepartmentsEntity> getDeps(){
    Query query = em.createQuery("select d from DepartmentsEntity d");
    return (List<DepartmentsEntity>) query.getResultList();
}

public DepartmentsEntity getDepById(int id){
    /*TypedQuery<DepartmentsEntity> query = em.createQuery(
            "Select d from DepartmentsEntity d where d.id = :id", DepartmentsEntity.class);
    return query.setParameter("id",id).getSingleResult();*/
    return em.find(DepartmentsEntity.class,id);
}
}
```

TestDepartmentsCRUD.java

```
package service;

/**
 * Created by Michele on 14/07/2017.
 */

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import database_table.DepartmentsEntity;
import database_table.ItemsEntity;

import java.util.List;

public class TestDepartmentsCRUD {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-example");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    DepartmentsCRUD departmentsCRUD = new DepartmentsCRUD(em);

    //////////////////////Get list of departments\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    /*List<DepartmentsEntity> listOfDepartments = departmentsCRUD.getDeps();
    for (DepartmentsEntity dep : listOfDepartments) {
        System.out.println("name : "+dep.getName());
    }*/

    //////////////////////Get dep by id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    DepartmentsEntity dep = departmentsCRUD.getDepById(1);
    System.out.println(dep.toString());
    List<ItemsEntity> items = dep.getItems();
    System.out.println("is empty? --> "+items.isEmpty());
    for(ItemsEntity item:items){
        System.out.println(item.toString());
    }
    em.close();
    emf.close();
}

}
```

here my log in console

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50573:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\envers\hibernate-envers-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\jpa-metamodel-generator\hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\c3p0\c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\c3p0\hibernate-c3p0-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\c3p0\mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\ehcache\ehcache-2.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\ehcache\hibernate-ehcache-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\ehcache\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\hibernate-infinispan-5.2.1.Final-tests.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\hibernate-infinispan-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\infinispan-commons-8.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\infinispan-core-8.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\jboss-marshalling-osgi-1.4.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\infinispan\jgroups-3.6.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\proxool\hibernate-proxool-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\optional\proxool\proxool-0.8.3.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\osgi\hibernate-osgi-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\osgi\org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\osgi\org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\cdi-api-1.1-PFD.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\el-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\required\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\mysql-connector-5.1.8.jar;C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\Test_Hibernate\lib\Hibernate_ORM\osgi\hibernate-osgi-5.2.1.Final-karaf.xml;C:\Users\Michele\Downloads\Hibernate_Tools_509.jar" service.TestDepartmentsCRUD
lug 17, 2017 5:10:56 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: jpa-example
    ...]
lug 17, 2017 5:10:56 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final}
lug 17, 2017 5:10:56 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
lug 17, 2017 5:10:56 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
lug 17, 2017 5:10:57 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/warehouse
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFORMAZIONI: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH10001007: JDBC isolation level: <unknown>
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@a96e5ebc [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@f7546cc7 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge8ml9pmi3x8z7v08zo|833051, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 2000, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 500, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@5db05a23 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge8ml9pmi3x8z7v08zo|16d6c1e, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/warehouse, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge8ml9pmi3x8z7v08zo|df6e3a, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
lug 17, 2017 5:10:58 PM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
///Departments///
ID:          1
name:        E-Items
lug 17, 2017 5:10:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
lug 17, 2017 5:10:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'items0_.items_ORDER' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentList.isEmpty(PersistentList.java:118)
    at service.TestDepartmentsCRUD.main(TestDepartmentsCRUD.java:35)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'items0_.items_ORDER' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2237)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 18 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

please Help me, Thank you anyway

Comment: The error states JPA is trying to use a "items_ORDER" field that doesn't exist.  This could be a JPA mapping default, suggesting you have an 'items' oneToMany or ManyToMany with some order class that is unidirectional and incorrectly mapped for the table structure, but you haven't shown anything that might relate.  Try letting JPA create the tables or DDL script for you and see where it might be different from what you are trying to use it against.

Comment: i don't understand what did you mean, how can do this?
because in my db and in Entity properties not have this field "items_ORDER" , i search in fully project path but didn't match with "ORDER"

Comment: Turn on your logging to finest and see what your logs tell you is happening, and the SQL that is generated.  They might tell you where or why this field is getting picked up, such as if your classpath includes something else from a different project, such as some Order entity.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown column 'items0_.items_ORDER' in 'field list'

This error line suggests that JPA is searching for items_ORDER in the ITEMS table. This indicates that you need to create this column in the Items table.

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "items",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column (name = "id")

Here mappedby = items means there should be items named field in the other table which will be binded.